# Sum of angles under which a fixed line segment is seen from points situated on another line segment

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

I have a question, like a picture attached below. I can find each angle by sin( or cosine) rule, but I think there is an easy way...a clue ...a concept which made it easy. can someone help me?
I do appreciate any hint.
[image]

for example to find $A$ I use $$BC=\sqrt 2, AC=6 , AB=\sqrt {26}\\\cos(A)=\frac{c^2+b^2-a^2}{2bc}=\frac{36+26-2}{2*6*\sqrt{26}}$$ then find $A=11.3099$ and do like this for all the angles. But it is not the satisfying method. ( the gray squares are equal)
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: As segments cut parallel lines, you either add them up at point $B$ or at point $C$. That I think gives you $90^\circ$.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? (In particular, the image.)

Comment: Please, could you answer the question of runway44 ?

Comment: A question with a similar solution [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/xn2pp8gm). This question has motivated my proposal of a new title for your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image: Visual Solution]

The equal angles in the solution come from the fact that $BCDE, BCEF, BCFG, BCGH, BCHA, BIAJ$ are all parallelograms. This is because $BC,ED$ have the same slope and so do $BE, CD$, etc. Then, $\angle BDC=\angle DBE$ etc. by alternate angles. All the angles put together add up to rotating $BD$ onto $BJ$. Since $BJ$ is vertical and $BD$ is horizontal, they then add to $90$ degrees.

(Thanks @ACB for tidying up the image)

Comment: @ACB Thanks so much!

Comment: Very fancy and lovely answer!

Comment: @Nightflight Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic mathematical insight!

Answer (score 11):

**Hint 1:**

The twelve line segments come in six parallel pairs.

**Hint 2:**

> Move the angles around so that the parallel lines match up.

**Solution:**

> [image]Excuse my poor paint skills.

Comment: thank you, but can you clarify a bit more? please

Comment: @Khosrotash I've added the corresponding picture.

Comment: Thank you I got the idea.